# How to remove iOS Simulator device label

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Is it possible to remove the bottom label from the simulator that says "iPhone X - 11.3"? I would like to take a screenshot without the label but include the device bevels and shadow.

[image]

Answer (score 55):

1. Press command + shift + 4.
2. Press spacebar

3a. Hold command + click the simulator (with shadow)

3b. Hold option + click the simulator (without shadow)

EDIT: With latest Xcode it's possible to use the Save Screen button on the Simulator (top) toolbar.

Comment: This is the simplest way! Don't need for another option application. Thanks a lot for this hack!

Comment: When doing this, the device frame is grey instead of black because it's not in focus.

Comment: Any idea how to leave the window toolbar out of a device screenshot in iOS 13.4? https://d.pr/i/CztnM4

Comment: It needs to be said that the simulator must NOT be the active window in order for this to work. And the bezels will also be greyed.

Answer (score 15):

For some reason, I can't get the `FloatingNameMode` setting to work anymore on Xcode 9.4

A solution I found by accident is the following:

1. Run the Simulator as you normally would.
2. Click somewhere on you desktop, in such way the Simulator is still visible (i.e. not blocked behind other windows) but no longer the active application.
3. Now the Simulator is no longer the active application, *the device label is now also gone* (and the Simulator frame went from black to dark grey).
4. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> ( add <kbd>control</kbd> if you want to save the screenshot to memory only) then press <kbd>space</kbd> and hover over the 'inactive' Simulator.
5. Press the keypad to take the screenshot. The screenshot is now saved without the device label.

Answer (score 7):

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator FloatingNameMode 2
```

That option is not guaranteed to work forever, but it works with current builds.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried this but I'm still see the labels in the simulator. I'm using Xcode 9.4.

Comment: Looks like you're right.  That recently broke but it wasn't intentional.  I've filed a radar (<rdar://problem/40757696>) for that and will make sure that it *does* solve your problem in a future update.

Comment: Working for me on the Simulator v 11.3.1

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to have iPhone's borders there is a hacky way to make a screenshot without the iPhone label.

Move the iPhone the way so that the label is not visible on the screen. As below:
[image]

After making a screenshot using: Shift+Cmd+4 > hover the simulator > press Space > press click on touch pad. It will take a screenshot of this area:
[image]

And then as a result you will have an image of simulator without the label:
[image]

Hope this answer was clear :)

Answer (score 0):

On 11.4, I had to use "3":

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator FloatingNameMode 3
```

Answer (score 0):

can use Terminal as well:

```
screencapture -l$(osascript -e 'tell app "Simulator" to id of window 1') screenshot.png
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Press command + shift + 5.
2. Hold command + click the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press command + shift + 5.
2. Choose "Capture selected window"
3. Choose "Options" and remove "Show floating thumbnail"
4. Left-click on the simulator to take the screenshot

**BONUS** The floating thumbnails won't appear any longer on your screenshot when using command + shift + 4 spacebar either