# How do you remove the iOS Simulator Label?

Tags: ios, xcode, label, simulator

This article explained how to take a screenshot:

[How to remove iOS Simulator device label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497045/how-to-remove-ios-simulator-device-label)

However, I need to record a video of the simulator using an application. How can I remove this label above the simulator?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can hide that with the latest Xcode 11.4 update.

You can screen record with QuickTime and a real device using a lightning cable.

[image: QuickTime New Movie Recording with iOS Device]

From File > New Movie Recording > Select Device next to Record button), and then add the video to a tool like [Rotato](https://www.rotato.xyz)

I'd recommend a static angle if you're playing a video.

[image: Rotato Video Rendering using Screenshot or Video]

See [Sean Allen's device render video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4ggqf7ZcDU) on how to use Rotato.